# How to id dom table so I can position it on page?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css

[image: Picture of tables]I am new to creating tables with js and started with using document.write. That was writing over my html so now I am using dom elements. How can I id the group of tables so I can position it in my css? I am a little confused how because my code creates multiple tables with the loop. I would just like to position them all as one. The picture shows what they look like but they just default to the bottom/left of my page. Also would appreciate any other code suggestions since I am new at this! Thanks!

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    BuildTable();

    function BuildTable() {
        var myUrl = window.location.href;
        PageMethods.DoStuff(myUrl, onSucess, onError);
        function onSucess(result) {

            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

                var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

                var tbl = document.createElement("table");
                var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

                    var row = document.createElement("tr");
                    var cell = document.createElement("td");
                    var cellText = document.createTextNode('Community: ' + result[i].apartName);
                    cell.appendChild(cellText);
                    row.appendChild(cell);
                    tblBody.appendChild(row);

                    row = document.createElement("tr");
                    cell = document.createElement("td");
                    cellText = document.createTextNode('Address: ' + result[i].address + ', ' + result[i].city);
                    cell.appendChild(cellText);
                    row.appendChild(cell);
                    tblBody.appendChild(row);

                tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
                body.appendChild(tbl);
                tbl.setAttribute("border", "1");
                var space = document.createElement("br");
                body.appendChild(space);
            }
            }

        function onError(result) {
            alert('Something wrong.');
        }
    }

 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the id:

```
tbl.setAttribute('id', thisTablesId );
```

But probably what you want is to set the `class` attribute instead. Those don't need to be unique. You can change the css styles (for positioning) of all tables with the same class at once. Or if you need to programmatically determine the styling, you can use that attribute to determine whether or not this is one of the elements you wanted.

```
tbl.setAttribute('class', 'built-table' );
```

In your css stylesheet you can define what the built-table class will include using the `.built-table` selector.

Comment: That worked except now my tables are all on top of eachother.

Comment: Are you using absolute positioning? If so, maybe they should be inside of a div and relatively positioned.

Comment: Yes I am. So can I create a div dom element or something?

Comment: You can create a main div with an id that is absolute positioned, then create child divs that are relatively positioned within that main div (rather than the `body` element as you are now).

Comment: I guess I am a little confused. I have an html div wrapped around the js and set the js table to relative. The tables are spaceing apart correctly but they will not sit inside of the div. The will only show at the bottom of it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30796/discussion-between-shadow-creeper-and-osiris355)